# Vim Macro to insert a space within surrounding characters?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vim, macros

Is there a Vim macro / shortcut that will allow me to insert a space within a surrounding input?

i.e.

```
/* before */
const arr = ["1", "2", "3"]
```

```
/* after */
const arr = [ "1", "2", "3" ]
```

(Right now I would do something like `f [ i <space> Esc f ] i <space>`, which is highly inefficient!)

A lot of formatters do this automatically, but I would love to to map this to a vim keybinding!

Answer (score 2):

You would need to replace the first `i` with an `a` for your macro to work correctly:

```
f[a<space><Esc>f]i<space>
```

Now, that macro may be inefficient if executed manually but not if done via a mapping:

```
nnoremap <key> f[a<space><Esc>f]i<space><Esc>
```

so I don't think your method needs any improvement.

FWIW, this would be a somewhat cleaner method:

```
ci[<space><C-r>"<space><Esc>
```

because there is less mode switching, but it is not particularly more efficient if executed manually and it would be just as efficient as any other method if reduced to a mapping.

Comment: Okay cool. I was looking if there was a way to leverage the Vim Surround plugin, where the editor would automatically detect the surrounding characters, to support (), {}, "", etc

Comment: Well, surround doesn't detect surrounding characters as it entirely depends upon text objects (as does my proposed "cleaner method").